# How to fix Integration Gateway: No response received from Gateway (158,10829) in Peoplesoft

Tags: elasticsearch, peoplesoft, broker

Lately I've been trying to deploy ElasticSearch on my 2 Dev Environments ( FSCM and HCM) which are on the same server.
I configured Gateways and Local Nodes on both environments.
On FSCM, i configured the default local Node **PSFT_EP** but also **PSFT_HR**; same on HCM.
But the ping works only on the 2 nodes in **FSCM**, but in **HCM** I can only ping ***PSFT_EP***, not ***PSFT_HR***, it shows me the following error: **Integration Gateway: No response received from Gateway (158,10829)** .
I checked PUBSUB on both environments and it's active, also the gateways are well configured same as the nodes.

Anyone please has already encountered the same error?

Comment: Is the gateway processes running on HCM? Are you doing one IBGW or a gateway per environment? Can you get the Listening URL?